# Properties of the Lie bracket space

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a Banach algebra with vector product $\otimes$. Let $[\cdot]$ denote the commutator with respect to the vector product, which defines a Lie bracket on $V$: i.e., for $v,w\in V$, $[v,w]:=v\otimes w - w\otimes v$.

What are the properties of the proper subspace $[V,V]:=\operatorname{span}\{ [v,w]: v,w\in V \}$?

Assume furthermore that $V$ is step-2 nilpotent, in the sense that $\forall \tilde{v} \in [V,V], \forall v \in V,  [\tilde{v},v]= 0 =[v,\tilde{v}]$. In other words, all commutators of depth greater than two vanish.

I am reading a proof (Proposition 2.7b, A Course on Rough Paths, Friz and Hairer, 2022) where they conclude easily that since:

$$\mathbb{X}_{s,t} - \frac{1}{2} X_{s,t} \otimes X_{s,t} \in [V,V]$$

It follows that (where the first equality follows by properties of the symmetrisation):
$$\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{X}_{s,t} - \frac{1}{2} X_{s,t} \otimes X_{s,t}) = \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{X}_{s,t}) - \frac{1}{2} X_{s,t} \otimes X_{s,t}=0. $$

However, I can’t seem to fathom why. Is there any chance that there are properties of this subspace that I ignore that you could help me with? I.e., if you are the Lie bracket of two vectors, what can I say about you? I can only think that the commutator with any element will be vanishing, but that does not get me very far.

NB: $$\operatorname{Sym}(v_1\otimes \ldots \otimes v_k):=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma_k} v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\ldots\otimes v_{\sigma(k)},$$ where $\Sigma_k$ are the permutations of length $k$ and extended by linearity to finite sums of products.

Comment: $[V,V]$ is not the set of $[v,w]$, but the linear span (as for groups, not the commutators, but the subgroup generated by them). If the Lie algebra is perfect, we have $V=[V,V]$. If it is $2$-step nilpotent, then $[V,[V,V]]=0$.

Comment: It seems you are missing the assumption of $(X, \mathbb{X})$ being weakly geometric, which makes $\mathbb{X}_{s,t} - \frac{1}{2} X_{s,t} \otimes X_{s,t} = \mathbb{X}_{s,t} - \text{Sym}(\mathbb{X}_{s,t})$ antisymmetric.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: @G.Chiusole Proposition 1.27b assumes that $\mathbf{X}_t$ is a $G^2(V):= \exp(V \oplus [V,V])$-valued path and defines $(1,X, \mathbb X)_{s,t}:=\mathbf{X}^{-1}_s\otimes \mathbf{X}_t $. Then, the proposition says that $(X, \mathbb X)_{s,t}$ so defined is wealy geometric, i.e. $\mathbb{X}_{s,t} - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Sym}(X_{s,t} \otimes X_{s,t})=0$. It says it is an easy consequence of the fact that $\mathbb{X}_{s,t} - \frac{1}{2} X_{s,t}\otimes X_{s,t}\in [V,V]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property needed is that an element of the Lie bracket is antisymmetric, i.e. its symmetric part is zero (or Sym of it is zero). Then, the equality becomes obvious.